# Can I get the short DOS name of a file from PHP?

Tags: php, dos

I want to pass a file path as a parameter to an executable from PHP, and the file path may contain spaces. The executable doesn't seem to handle quotes around the parameter, so I thought maybe I could pass the short DOS name instead of the long name.

Does PHP know anything about the old-style DOS 8.3 file names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

php/win32 ships with the [COM/.net extension built-in](http://de.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php). You can use it to create a WSH [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(VS.85).aspx) and then query the [ShortPath property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htyh9b2z(VS.85).aspx) of the [File object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(VS.85).aspx).

```
<?php
$objFSO = new COM("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
$objFile = $objFSO->GetFile(FILE);
echo "path: ", $objFile->Path, "\nshort path: ", $objFile->ShortPath;
```

prints e.g.

```
path: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Volker\Desktop\test.php
short path: C:\DOKUME~1\Volker\Desktop\test.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at `escapeshellarg()` and put the parameter in between double quotes.

Comment: I thought that should work, too. It works when I execute the dir command, but not when I execute the command I'm trying to run.

Comment: use escapeshellcmd() to escape the executable, and escapeshellarg() for the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't understand escapeshellcmd at all. On Windows, it just appears to replace special characters with spaces. 'C:\Documents and Settings\don\foo' becomes 'C: Documents and Settings don foo'. How is that useful?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(VS.85).aspx) API in Kernel32 on windows.  To call this from PHP, you will need to use the [Win32 API extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.w32api.php)...

Comment: That would probably be faster. Unfortunately I can't test it because the php 5.3rc2 build came without the w32 module :-/ Hope you don't mind me adding the links to your post.

Answer (score 0):

How about backslashing the space?

```
Home/My Documents/  --> Home/My\ Documents/
```

Comment: The executable I'm trying to run treats the backslash as part of the name. In your example it would try to open the file Home/My\

Comment: You probably want escapeshellarg as suggested by phphil. You would escape with a backslash if calling directly from the command line